# Delete rows older than 10 time periods under each group

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with 2 columns

```
+---------+------------+
| symbol  | ts         |
+---------+------------+
|       1 | 1524696300 |
|       1 | 1524697200 |
|       1 | 1524698100 |
|       1 | 1524699000 |
|       1 | 1524699900 |
|       1 | 1524700800 |
|       1 | 1524701700 |
|       1 | 1524702600 |
|       1 | 1524703500 |
|       1 | 1524704400 |
|       1 | 1524705300 |
|       1 | 1524706200 |
|       2 | 1524697200 |
|       2 | 1524698100 |
|       2 | 1524699000 |
|       2 | 1524699900 |
+---------+------------+
```

I want to remove older than 10 rows under each group, each row is separated by 900 seconds and may have different timestamp values at the first and last row but the difference of 900 remains constant

I tried this query

```
sqlite> select * from ohlc2 where ts < (select max(ts) from ohlc2) - 8100;
```

It only works on the table as a whole and not per group so if my item 1 and 2 have different starting and ending timestamps, the above method wont work

I am getting an error in this query which I tried now

```
sqlite> with m as (select symbol, max(ts) from ohlc2 group by symbol) select * from ohlc2 where symbol = m.symbol and ts < m.max - 8100;
```

How can I delete all rows older than 10 timestamps per group?

Comment: If the first query works but doesn't account for groups....why not just change the inner select query to account for them with maybe a `where` clause?

Comment: What's the specific error that you're getting from your second query? I don't know why people do this all the time... "I'm getting *an* error" isn't nearly as helpful in identifying an issue as, "I'm getting *this* error: ..." My guess is that you didn't give an alias for the second column in your CTE, but the fact that I'm guessing isn't great.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite, you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
delete ohlc2
    where ts < (select o2.ts
                from ohlc2 o2
                where o2.symbol = ohlc2.symbol
                order by o2.ts desc
                limit 1 offset 9
               );
```

Comment: just tested, this works!!! thank you very much upvoted ya, will the condition inside where be evaluated for each row? there is a syntax error Error: near "o": syntax error :)

Comment: @PirateApp . . . Yes.  But if you have an index on `(symbol, ts)`, then that is a minor issue.

Answer (score 0):

I primarily work with MS SQL Server, so I don't know if SQLLite supports this syntax or not, but if this is valid syntax in SQLLite, then it should work:

```
DELETE T1
FROM OHLC2 T1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            symbol,
            MAX(ts) AS max_ts
        FROM
            OHLC2
    ) SQ ON SQ.symbol = T1.symbol AND SQ.max_ts > T1.ts + 8100
```

Should also work with a CTE as you have it, but you need to name your second column in the CTE with an alias.

Comment: thanks! upvoted for your effort, I tried select * from ohlc2 t1 INNER JOIN (select symbol, max(ts) as max_ts from ohlc2) s on s.symbol = t1.symbol and s.max_ts > t1.ts + 8100;
 and it only removes the older entries from one group